# when i click label, prompts make result

Tags: javascript, html, label, prompt

I make HTML file and js file but i had some problems.

In HTML there are 5 labels tag(and there's no specific `id` or `class` name) and when i click each label, pop-up(prompt) appear, and it make result(change style).

Changing style is not difficult so i am okay but i have a problem in prompt.

I wrote this code:

```
function changeCol(evnt) {
    var theEvent = evnt ? evnt : window.event;
        var label = document.getElementsByTagName("label");
        label[0].addEventListener ("click", function (){
            var one = prompt("Enter the color");
            label[0].style.color = one;
        });

        label[1].addEventListener ("click", function (){
            var two = prompt("Enter the color");
            label[1].style.color = two;
        });

        label[2].addEventListener ("click", function (){
            var three = prompt("Enter the color");
            label[2].style.color = three;
        });
    }
```

But when i click a label first, it is okay buy when i click 2nd prompt appear twice... and 3rd click show prompt three times...

And when i want to see prompt i have to click twice and maybe it is because of function. In js there.

```
function loadevent(){ ...
         if (label){
        for (i=0;i < label.length; i++){
         label[i].onclick = changeCol;
        }
    }
}
```

What should i do?

Answer (score 1):

Hi try using the below code snippet:-

```
var label = document.getElementsByTagName("label");
    function changeCol(element) {

        element.addEventListener ("click", function (){
            var promcolor= prompt("Enter the color");
            element.style.color = promcolor;

        });
    }

    function loadevent(){ 
         if (label){
            for (i=0;i < label.length; i++){
                changeCol(label[i]);
            }
        }
    }
loadevent();
```

And I assumed below HTML

```
<p><label for="1">label-1</label></p>
<p><label for="2">label-2</label></p>
<p><label for="3">label-3</label></p>
```

I dont see much use of loadevent function . But seeing the dots I assume there is some other code there. But if its not you can simply have one function like below:

```
function loadevent(){        
            for (itr=0;itr < label.length; itr++){
                label[itr].addEventListener ("click", function (){
                    var promcolor= prompt("Enter the color");
                    this.style.color = promcolor;   
                });
            }
    }
```

Also the issue with your code was even while you iterate the element in loadevent function you add event listeners for all labels.  This wont happen with this code.

Answer (score 1):

**Problem:**

The problem with your actual code is that for each label you use this label's index and loop according to this index an alert a prompt, that's why you get only one prompt with the first label, two prompts with the second and three with the third label.

**Solution:**

The best approach is to use `addEventListener` like in your first function and loop through all labels using `document.getElementsByTagName("label")`and use `this` keyword to change color of the `clicked label` inside the loop, here's what you need :

```js
  var labels = document.getElementsByTagName("label");
  for (i = 0; i < labels.length; i++) {
    labels[i].addEventListener("click", function() {
      var prmt = prompt("Enter the color");
      this.style.color = prmt;
    });
  }
```

```html
<label> A</label><br>
<label> B</label><br>
<label> C</label><br>
<label> D</label><br>
<label> E</label><br>
```

**Note:**
Using this code you don't need to specify any `id` or `class` or other attribute to your labels.

And then you just need to put this code inside your load function and call it in windows load:

```
function loadevent(){
  var labels = document.getElementsByTagName("label");
  for (i = 0; i < labels.length; i++) {
    labels[i].addEventListener("click", function() {
      var prmt = prompt("Enter the color");
      this.style.color = prmt;
    });
  }
]
```

Comment: This is the best answer according to me for this question.

Answer (score 0):

here you have written script of opening prompt in for loop hence it generate multiple popup depending on label number. i.e if you clicked on 4th label then it will open prompt 4 times.

To avoid this you have to pass index of current label.

```
function loadevent(){ 
         if (label){
        for (i=0;i < label.length; i++){
         label[i].onclick = changeCol(i);
        }
    }
}

function changeCol(index,evnt) {

    var theEvent = evnt ? evnt : window.event;
        var label = document.getElementsByTagName("label");
        label[index].addEventListener ("click", function (){
            var current_color = prompt("Enter the color");
            label[index].style.color = current_color;  
        });

    }
```

This may helps you.

Comment: Actually this will raise an Exception `label is not defined` in your loadevent function.

Comment: Hi inside addEventListener refering element as 'label[index]' will cause what 'label is not defined' error as said by @chsdk